# In Hibernate Validator, how can the method validation tell the caller that the return value may be null?

Tags: hibernate-validator, notnull

The method validation in Hibernate Validator can tell callers that the return value is `@NotNull`, but how can I tell the caller that the return value might be null? In Findbugs, I have `@CheckForNull`, but that's only active at compile time, not at run time.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you are asking for something like *@Nullable*. That is not part of Bean Validation and most likely won't be. See also the discussion of the expert group around this - http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/beanvalidation-dev/2013-January/thread.html

What can you achieve with a @Nullable anyways. In the context of Bean Validation, the implementation would just always return true.

Comment: Well, it would be an alternative to compile-time checks with JSR-305. I agree that in a validation context, it doesn't make sense. But then mixing JSR-303 and JSR-305 annotation doesn't make a lot of sense, either  ;-)